# PHP - array_diff does not work as it supposed to

Tags: php, arrays, diff

Just found a strange behavior of PHP with the `array_diff` function.

I have the following arrays:

```
    $d1 = [
        'HomePhoneNumber' => '555-222-2222',
        'MobilePhoneNumber' => NULL,
        'ContactID' => NULL,
        'ApplicantID' => '2'
    ];
    
    
    $d2 = [
        'HomePhoneNumber' => '555-222-2222',
        'MobilePhoneNumber' => '555-222-3333',
        'ContactID' => '1',
        'ApplicantID' => '2'
    ];
```

I need to find the values from `$d2` which are not present into `$d1`:

```
array_diff($d2, $d1)
```

The function returns me:

```
array (
  'MobilePhoneNumber' => '555-222-3333',
  'ContactID' => '1',
)
```

This is correct!

But, if I compare the same arrays with a different value of `'ContactID'` key, the `array_diff()` function returns me a different result (`'ContactID'` is no longer returned):

```
    $d1 = [
        'HomePhoneNumber' => '555-222-2222',
        'MobilePhoneNumber' => NULL,
        'ContactID' => NULL,
        'ApplicantID' => '2'
    ];
    
    
    $d2 = [
        'HomePhoneNumber' => '555-222-2222',
        'MobilePhoneNumber' => '555-222-3333',
        'ContactID' => '2',
        'ApplicantID' => '2'
    ];

// Result:
array (
  'MobilePhoneNumber' => '555-222-3333',
)
```

Do you know why? I don't understand.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: Obviously, `array_diff` __does not consider__ keys. And value '2' exists in `$d1`

Comment: It might be a side effect of type juggling between the null and the string, see [Example #2 array_diff() example with non-matching types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#example-4934) you could see if you can create a custom comparison using [array_udiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_diff` only checks for values, no checks for keys

you need to use [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to check along with keys

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.  By 2015, virtually all basic questions have been asked and answered 5 or more times.  This means that when you see a new basic question asked, it is probably a duplicate (it is not low-hanging fruit, it is forbidden fruit).